# Print a coordinates marker in 2D array of objects. Java

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array, coordinates

I'm trying to print out an indicator of coordinates on a 2D array...
There is another class that I've used to instantiate objects on the array.

I need to the store coordinates in two (local?) variables, and then display the position of those coordinates in the printed array. (that has already been instantiated with various objects)

This is a snippet of code I have so far, but I can't get the 'C' to print in the right spot on the array. The few options that I tired, either doesn't print it at all, or prints the 'C' in the top left hand corner.

This is one option that I've tired: This option doesn't print the 'C' at all.

```
   private int cX=0;
   private int cY=0;

     //Randomly set coordinates on array.

       for(int i=0; i<array.length; i++){
            for(int j=0; j<array[i].length; j++){
                int x = randGen.nextInt(9);
                int y = randGen.nextInt(9);
                if (array [x][y].display()=='.'){
                    x=cX;
                    y=cY;
                }
             }
         }


    // print array

    private void displayArray()
    {

      for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++){ 
        for (int j = 0; j < array[i].length; j++){
           if ((array [i][j].display()==cX)&&
                (array [i][j].display()==cY))
                System.out.print("C");
                System.out.print(board [i][j].display()+"\t")   
         }
            System.out.println("\n");
      }
    }
```

Comment: Could you rephrase your question, and possibly give an example?

Comment: Sorry, hard to explain. I need to store coordinates in two local variables, and then display the position of the those coordinates in the printed array. (that has already been instantiated with various objects)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For completeness: I think I worked it out. (Well it seems to be working anyway).
Thanks for the help!

```
  private int cX=0;
  private int cY=0;


  //Randomly set coordinates on the array. 
 for(int i=0; i<1; i++){
  int x = randGen.nextInt(9);
  int y = randGen.nextInt(9);
  if (board [x][y].display()=='.'){
   CX=x;
   CY=y;
  }
 }  


 //Print array
private void displayArray(){
 for (int i = 0; i < board.length; i++){ 
  for (int j = 0; j < board[i].length; j++){
   if ((i==CX)&&(j==CY))
    System.out.print("C"+"\t");
   else
    System.out.print(board [i][j].display()+"\t");
  }
 System.out.println("\n");
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you right, you'd like to save coordinates to some kind of data structure and later display them?

Wouldn't it be suitable to create a class for this purpose? E.g.
A class called Coordinator, that holds the X & Y values.

Later create a object of the class you've made with X & Y values and put it to a ArrayList.

Code Example:

```
//Creating the a object holding 2 values
Coordinator cords = new Coordinator(randGen.nextInt(9), randGen.nextInt(9));

//Putting in the object to the data structure
List<Coordinator> list = new ArrayList<>();
list.add(cords);
```

The explanation and code example should help you solve this issue on your own hopefully.

Comment: Yes, I think it would. Though I'm doing an assignment and one of the requirements is that it is not an object. It has to be row and column coordinates, tracked and displayed in the array.

Answer (score 0):

> This option doesn't print the 'C' at all.

Your current code example will indeed never print a 'C'.

```
for (int j = 0; j < array[i].length; j++){
if ((array [i][j].display()==cX)&&
       (array [i][j].display()==cY))
```

This *if* condition will be true only if cX equals cY and both are equal to the ascii code value assigned to the array (for '.' this is the value 46). But you may just want to find the cX,cY position and print a 'C'. You should try to campare your position (cX, cY) with the current i and j values.

```
if ((i==cX)&&(j==cY))
```

> prints the 'C' in the top left hand corner

You never change the content of array at the position. You set x and y which will be overwritten and are later no accessible

```
int x = randGen.nextInt(9);
int y = randGen.nextInt(9);
if (array [x][y].display()=='.'){
      x=cX;
      y=cY;
}
```

Do you want to find a random position for your 'C' to appear, like in a board game?
Then you need to assign your found x and y coordinate to cX and cY. The right value gets assigned to the left variable.

```
cX = x;
cY = y;
```

I hope I understood you right and this helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
  private double[][] mLatLng = {
                {19.01062463, 73.01141475},
                {19.02369039, 73.00778391},};
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) { googleMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);
    Bitmap icon = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.ic_icon);
    for (int i = 0; i < mLatLng.length; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < mLatLng[i].length; j++) {
    googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
    .position(new LatLng(mLatLng[i][j], mLatLng[i][j]))
    .title("Location" + i).icon(bitmapDescriptorFromVector(context,R.drawable.ic_icon)));
```

Comment: Please put your answer always in context instead of just pasting code. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) for more details.